# global ajaxError event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i have a global ajaxError event in my base.master, something like this

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings,thrownError) {
    $("#results").append( "<li>some error msg.</li>" );
    });
```

but i dont want to use "#results". i want it to be dynamic. i want the function to always display the error msg in the update-target element.  how can i find the UpdateTarget Id that was used from my ajax call in the error event? thanks.

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", null, 
           new AjaxOptions { 
           UpdateTargetId = "results", <--find this element in my error event
           LoadingElementId = "loading",
```

Comment: Isn't it in the settings variable?

Comment: where in the settings, I check jquery documantation, but it dont say whats in the settings param.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with ASP, but the `ajaxError` receives all settings that are passed to the `ajax` method in the aptly named `settings` variable.

So if you have an AJAX call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some/url.asp',
    data: myData,
    resultsEle: $('#myResults')
});
```

You can access `resultsEle` in the `ajaxError` like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, thrownError) {
    settings.resultsEle.append( "<li>some error msg.</li>" );
});
```

Again, I am not familiar with the way you are calling the AJAX method in your ASP code, but my guess would be you can get to the element this way:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, thrownError) {
    $('#'+settings.UpdateTargetId).append( "<li>some error msg.</li>" );
});
```